# How to check if a specific Javascript Function running and terminating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check and if exist stop javascript function?
I have a counting down JS code bottom;

```
            function Countdown(options) {
                var timer,
                    instance = this,
                    seconds = options.seconds || 10,
                    perTurn = options.perTurn || 1000,
                    updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function() {},
                    counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function() {};

                function decrementCounter() {
                    updateStatus(seconds);
                    if (seconds === 0) {
                        counterEnd();
                        instance.stop();
                    }
                    seconds--;
                }

                this.start = function() {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    timer = 0;
                    seconds = options.seconds;
                    timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, perTurn);
                };

                this.stop = function() {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                };
            }

            function CountDownToPlay(userID) {
                var myCounter = new Countdown({
                    seconds: 20,
                    perTurn: 2000,
                    onUpdateStatus: function (sec) {
                        console.log(sec);
                    },
                    onCounterEnd: function () {}
                });
                myCounter.start();
            }
```

It's counting down from more than 20 seconds, but manytime I must terminate the process...

How can I kill current javascript process? And check if it is exist?

***DEMO:***
http://jsfiddle.net/Ercin/gmt04nx9/

Comment: Why down vote? Please explain?

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded (except for web workers, which you aren't using). There is nothing to check and nothing to kill. You need to keep a reference to the `Countdown` object and manage its state yourself.

Comment: In node.js it is possible to create several processes

Answer (score 2):

The object implements a `stop` function, why don't you just call it?

`myCounter.stop();`

To know if it *exists* should be easy enough since it's your code that's instanciating `Countdown` instances...

Comment: +1, Thanks for the answer; <button onclick="Countdown.stop();">STOP</button> it is not working like this or <button onclick="CountDownToPlay.stop();">STOP</button>   http://jsfiddle.net/Ercin/gmt04nx9/

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu You must call `stop` on the `Countdown` **instance** you want to stop (the one created with `new`). Not on the constructor itself. You will first need to make the `myCounter` variable globally accessible and then put `onclick="myCounter.stop();`"

Comment: could you give me a small sample please? :]

Answer (score 1):

Typically unless you set up a flag somewhere, it is not possible to check if a javascript function is running somewhere.

However, if you need this information, you can set up a global variable and switch it on/off when your process starts / ends. You also should construct a global variable like "killProc" that the procedure checks on intermittently, and exits if it is true.

For more, check out Java's Thread.interrupt() concept.